# Move an untagged table with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to find a jQuery/JavaScript method of moving a table. The platform my site uses is completely locked down, so I am unable to add, change, or remove any classes from page elements.

The tricky part of what I need to accomplish is this: The table element I need to move does not have an id or class.

I have set up a jsfiddle with the structure of the html so you can see it first hand. Anyone have any suggestions? http://jsfiddle.net/1hppk5kh/1/

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="content_area">
        <table><tr><td>I need to target and move this entire table</td></tr></table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table></table>
                    <table></table>
                    <!--Where I want the table to end up-->
                    <form id="MainForm"></form>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If your code is locked down how are you using js to modify it?

Comment: I can add script to the page via a template file. However the inner HTML of the category pages is un-editible by me. This is why the script must be conditional to the page URL. It will be loaded on all website pages.

Comment: OK, so is anything else about the table that you can use to identify it? i.e. It's always the 5th table on the page. Or it always follows a particular <div>, etc.

Comment: As far as CSS goes, it would be easy for me to identify: div#content_area + table

Comment: ok, so what is causing you the problem? And, where do you want to move your table to?

Comment: There's not a problem necessarily. I just don't have the technical coding prowess to accomplish this coding feat. If you check out the fiddle, it shows where I would like it moved to.

Answer (score 1):

Some simple jQuery should do the trick:

```
$('#content_area table:eq(0)').insertBefore('#MainForm');
```

Unpacked: `$('#content_area table:eq(0)')` searches inside `#content_area` for the *first* (`:eq(0)`) `table` element. Then this element is moved to before the `#MainForm` element.

Comment: Looks good Geoffrey. Would you mind including the conditional URL detection bit in your answer?

Comment: That isn’t really part of this question. I edited the question to remove it.

Comment: Per the guidelines for the site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Questions should be as streamlined as possible. That's why 'Hello' and 'Thanks' etc. are deleted automatically. The fact that you need to do this only on certain pages isn’t really relevant to the question of 'How do I move this table?'.

Comment: I agree with Geoffrey. It's ok to ask one question but to effectively ask for the whole solution to be done for you is another thing. Spend a little time looking up https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else etc.

Comment: In case you're interested at all, the answer you provided here is targeting the correct table, and a number of additional tables deeper in the HTML of the #MainForm div, so it is unusable.

Comment: The above answer works with the code you provided. Try it in your fiddle and you’ll see. As for your real HTML, I suggest you post another question with the real HTML and people can take a crack at it. The whole point of [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) is that only one element is selected (in this case, the 0th, or first, matching element) so there shouldn’t be other tables affected.